# Codeigniter index function

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, authentication

All Codeigniter controllers seem to start with:

```
public function index()
{
  // stuff
}
```

Is this a requirement or just good practice? I have an instance where an index may not be needed, for example I have a controller called "Auth" and in it there is a function to **register** and a function to **login** - you could argue that the login function is of higher priority but in the interest of naming convention I would rather name my functions. What is best practice here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a **must** method. It simply behaves like `index.html` on apache server.

When there is no `html` file specified, it automatically goes to `index.html`.

The same here, when there is no controller method specified `index` is default.

Answer (score 7):

The `index` method is simply what's called when the second URL segment is missing. For example:

```
class Auth extends CI_Controller {

    public function index () {
        // domain.com/auth
        // domain.com/auth/index
    }

    public function register () {
        // domain.com/auth/register
    }
}
```

If you don't need that route, you don't need an `index` method.

Comment: I have two routes - login and register, so an index seems futile. I'll probably remove the index. Thanks!